# "java.io.IOException" in compileSdkVersion 28

Tags: java, android, gradle, sdk, android-gradle-plugin

My project had no issues but met with a small error recently so i clicked on 'invalidate and restart' option for fixing some error. That error was fixed and now i cant Build my Porject

The Error when i Rebuild Project

Error:Execution failed for task ':app:transformClassesWithMultidexlistForDebug'.

> java.io.IOException: Can't write [D:\MessagePlus\app\build\intermediates\multi-dex\debug\componentClasses.jar] (Can't read [C:\Users\Akash.gradle\caches\transforms-1\files-1.1\versionedparcelable-1.0.0.aar\6c766194e4753f670df775fbe4f9a9b0\jars\classes.jar(;;;;;;**.class)] (Duplicate zip entry [classes.jar:androidx/versionedparcelable/CustomVersionedParcelable.class]))

Error is Console

```
* Exception is:
org.gradle.api.tasks.TaskExecutionException: Execution failed for task 
':app:transformClassesWithMultidexlistForDebug'.
at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.executeActions(ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.java:100)
at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.execute(ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.java:70)
at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.SkipUpToDateTaskExecuter.execute(SkipUpToDateTaskExecuter.java:63)
at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.ResolveTaskOutputCachingStateExecuter.execute(ResolveTaskOutputCachingStateExecuter.java:54)
at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.ValidatingTaskExecuter.execute(ValidatingTaskExecuter.java:58)
at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.SkipEmptySourceFilesTaskExecuter.execute(SkipEmptySourceFilesTaskExecuter.java:88)
at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.ResolveTaskArtifactStateTaskExecuter.execute(ResolveTaskArtifactStateTaskExecuter.java:52)
at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.SkipTaskWithNoActionsExecuter.execute(SkipTaskWithNoActionsExecuter.java:52)
at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.SkipOnlyIfTaskExecuter.execute(SkipOnlyIfTaskExecuter.java:54)
at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.ExecuteAtMostOnceTaskExecuter.execute(ExecuteAtMostOnceTaskExecuter.java:43)
at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.CatchExceptionTaskExecuter.execute(CatchExceptionTaskExecuter.java:34)
at org.gradle.execution.taskgraph.DefaultTaskGraphExecuter$EventFiringTaskWorker$1.run(DefaultTaskGraphExecuter.java:248)
at org.gradle.internal.progress.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor$RunnableBuildOperationWorker.execute(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:336)
at org.gradle.internal.progress.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor$RunnableBuildOperationWorker.execute(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:328)
at org.gradle.internal.progress.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.execute(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:197)
at org.gradle.internal.progress.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.run(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:107)
at org.gradle.execution.taskgraph.DefaultTaskGraphExecuter$EventFiringTaskWorker.execute(DefaultTaskGraphExecuter.java:241)
at org.gradle.execution.taskgraph.DefaultTaskGraphExecuter$EventFiringTaskWorker.execute(DefaultTaskGraphExecuter.java:230)
at org.gradle.execution.taskgraph.DefaultTaskPlanExecutor$TaskExecutorWorker.processTask(DefaultTaskPlanExecutor.java:124)
at org.gradle.execution.taskgraph.DefaultTaskPlanExecutor$TaskExecutorWorker.access$200(DefaultTaskPlanExecutor.java:80)
at org.gradle.execution.taskgraph.DefaultTaskPlanExecutor$TaskExecutorWorker$1.execute(DefaultTaskPlanExecutor.java:105)
at org.gradle.execution.taskgraph.DefaultTaskPlanExecutor$TaskExecutorWorker$1.execute(DefaultTaskPlanExecutor.java:99)
at org.gradle.execution.taskgraph.DefaultTaskExecutionPlan.execute(DefaultTaskExecutionPlan.java:625)
at org.gradle.execution.taskgraph.DefaultTaskExecutionPlan.executeWithTask(DefaultTaskExecutionPlan.java:580)
at org.gradle.execution.taskgraph.DefaultTaskPlanExecutor$TaskExecutorWorker.run(DefaultTaskPlanExecutor.java:99)
at org.gradle.internal.concurrent.ExecutorPolicy$CatchAndRecordFailures.onExecute(ExecutorPolicy.java:63)
at org.gradle.internal.concurrent.ManagedExecutorImpl$1.run(ManagedExecutorImpl.java:46)
at org.gradle.internal.concurrent.ThreadFactoryImpl$ManagedThreadRunnable.run(ThreadFactoryImpl.java:55)

Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException: java.io.IOException: Can't write [D:\MessagePlus\app\build\intermediates\multi-dex\debug\componentClasses.jar] (Can't read [C:\Users\Akash\.gradle\caches\transforms-1\files-1.1\versionedparcelable-1.0.0.aar\6c766194e4753f670df775fbe4f9a9b0\jars\classes.jar(;;;;;;**.class)] (Duplicate zip entry [classes.jar:androidx/versionedparcelable/CustomVersionedParcelable.class]))
at com.android.builder.profile.Recorder$Block.handleException(Recorder.java:55)
at com.android.builder.profile.ThreadRecorder.record(ThreadRecorder.java:104)
at com.android.build.gradle.internal.pipeline.TransformTask.transform(TransformTask.java:213)
at org.gradle.internal.reflect.JavaMethod.invoke(JavaMethod.java:73)
at org.gradle.api.internal.project.taskfactory.DefaultTaskClassInfoStore$IncrementalTaskAction.doExecute(DefaultTaskClassInfoStore.java:173)
at org.gradle.api.internal.project.taskfactory.DefaultTaskClassInfoStore$StandardTaskAction.execute(DefaultTaskClassInfoStore.java:134)
at org.gradle.api.internal.project.taskfactory.DefaultTaskClassInfoStore$StandardTaskAction.execute(DefaultTaskClassInfoStore.java:121)
at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter$1.run(ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.java:122)
at org.gradle.internal.progress.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor$RunnableBuildOperationWorker.execute(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:336)
at org.gradle.internal.progress.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor$RunnableBuildOperationWorker.execute(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:328)
at org.gradle.internal.progress.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.execute(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:197)
at org.gradle.internal.progress.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.run(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:107)
at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.executeAction(ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.java:111)
at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.executeActions(ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.java:92)
... 27 more

Caused by: java.io.IOException: Can't write [D:\MessagePlus\app\build\intermediates\multi-dex\debug\componentClasses.jar] (Can't read [C:\Users\Akash\.gradle\caches\transforms-1\files-1.1\versionedparcelable-1.0.0.aar\6c766194e4753f670df775fbe4f9a9b0\jars\classes.jar(;;;;;;**.class)] (Duplicate zip entry [classes.jar:androidx/versionedparcelable/CustomVersionedParcelable.class]))
at proguard.OutputWriter.writeOutput(OutputWriter.java:187)
at proguard.OutputWriter.execute(OutputWriter.java:79)
at proguard.ProGuard.writeOutput(ProGuard.java:427)
at proguard.ProGuard.execute(ProGuard.java:175)
at com.android.build.gradle.internal.transforms.BaseProguardAction.runProguard(BaseProguardAction.java:61)
at com.android.build.gradle.internal.transforms.MainDexListTransform.shrinkWithProguard(MainDexListTransform.java:232)
at com.android.build.gradle.internal.transforms.MainDexListTransform.transform(MainDexListTransform.java:184)
at com.android.build.gradle.internal.pipeline.TransformTask$2.call(TransformTask.java:222)
at com.android.build.gradle.internal.pipeline.TransformTask$2.call(TransformTask.java:218)
at com.android.builder.profile.ThreadRecorder.record(ThreadRecorder.java:102)
... 39 more

Caused by: java.io.IOException: Can't read [C:\Users\Akash\.gradle\caches\transforms-1\files-1.1\versionedparcelable-1.0.0.aar\6c766194e4753f670df775fbe4f9a9b0\jars\classes.jar(;;;;;;**.class)] (Duplicate zip entry [classes.jar:androidx/versionedparcelable/CustomVersionedParcelable.class])
at proguard.InputReader.readInput(InputReader.java:188)
at proguard.InputReader.readInput(InputReader.java:158)
at proguard.OutputWriter.writeOutput(OutputWriter.java:176)
... 48 more

Caused by: java.io.IOException: Duplicate zip entry [classes.jar:androidx/versionedparcelable/CustomVersionedParcelable.class]
at proguard.io.JarWriter.getOutputStream(JarWriter.java:138)
at proguard.io.FilteredDataEntryWriter.getOutputStream(FilteredDataEntryWriter.java:106)
at proguard.io.FilteredDataEntryWriter.getOutputStream(FilteredDataEntryWriter.java:106)
at proguard.io.FilteredDataEntryWriter.getOutputStream(FilteredDataEntryWriter.java:92)
at proguard.io.ClassRewriter.read(ClassRewriter.java:68)
at proguard.io.FilteredDataEntryReader.read(FilteredDataEntryReader.java:87)
at proguard.io.FilteredDataEntryReader.read(FilteredDataEntryReader.java:87)
at proguard.io.FilteredDataEntryReader.read(FilteredDataEntryReader.java:87)
at proguard.io.JarReader.read(JarReader.java:65)
at proguard.io.DirectoryPump.readFiles(DirectoryPump.java:65)
at proguard.io.DirectoryPump.pumpDataEntries(DirectoryPump.java:53)
at proguard.InputReader.readInput(InputReader.java:184)
... 50 more
```

My Gradle

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {


compileSdkVersion 28
buildToolsVersion "28.0.3"
defaultConfig {
    applicationId 'com.scorpion.messageplus'
    minSdkVersion 17
    targetSdkVersion 28
    versionCode 4
    versionName "1.0.2"
    //noinspection GradleCompatible
    //noinspection GradleCompatible
    testInstrumentationRunner "android.support.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
    multiDexEnabled true
}
buildTypes {
    release {
        minifyEnabled false
        proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
    }
}
productFlavors {
}
    //packagingOptions {
    //exclude 'META-INF/ASL2.0'
    //exclude 'META-INF/androidx.localbroadcastmanager_localbroadcastmanager.version'
    //exclude 'META-INF/androidx.swiperefreshlayout_swiperefreshlayout.version'
    //exclude 'META-INF/androidx.cursoradapter_cursoradapter.version'
    //exclude 'META-INF/androidx.drawerlayout_drawerlayout.version'
    //exclude 'META-INF/androidx.print_print.version'
    //exclude 'META-INF/androidx.versionedparcelable_versionedparcelable.version'
    //noinspection GradleCompatible
    //exclude 'META-INF/androidx.interpolator_interpolator.version'
    //exclude 'META-INF/androidx.fragment_fragment.version'
    //exclude 'META-INF/androidx.customview_customview.version'
    //exclude 'META-INF/androidx.documentfile_documentfile.version'
    //exclude 'META-INF/androidx.legacy_legacy-support-core-utils.version'
    //exclude 'META-INF/androidx.loader_loader.version'
    //exclude 'META-INF/androidx.viewpager_viewpager.version'
    //exclude 'META-INF/androidx.asynclayoutinflater_asynclayoutinflater.version'
    //exclude 'META-INF/androidx.core_core.version'
    //exclude 'META-INF/proguard/androidx-annotations.pro'
    //exclude 'META-INF/androidx.appcompat_appcompat.version'
    //exclude 'META-INF/androidx.vectordrawable_vectordrawable.version'
    //exclude 'META-INF/androidx.vectordrawable_vectordrawable-animated.version'
    //exclude 'META-INF/androidx.slidingpanelayout_slidingpanelayout.version'
    //exclude 'META-INF/androidx.coordinatorlayout_coordinatorlayout.version'
    //exclude 'META-INF/androidx.legacy_legacy-support-core-ui.version'
    //}
}


dependencies{

//noinspection GradleCompatible
androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test:runner:1.0.2'
androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.0.2'

testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.12'

implementation fileTree(include: ['*.jar'], dir: 'libs')
implementation 'com.android.support.constraint:constraint-layout:1.1.3'

//noinspection GradleCompatible
implementation 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:28.0.0'
implementation 'com.android.support:support-v4:28.0.0'
implementation 'com.android.support:design:28.0.0'
implementation 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:28.0.0'

implementation 'com.unstoppable:submitbutton:1.1.3'
implementation 'com.squareup.picasso:picasso:2.71828'
implementation 'com.github.yukuku:ambilwarna:2.0.1'
implementation 'com.github.bumptech.glide:glide:4.6.1'
implementation 'com.github.siyamed:android-shape-imageview:0.9.3@aar'
implementation 'com.theartofdev.edmodo:android-image-cropper:2.7.0'

implementation 'com.android.volley:volley:1.0.0'

implementation 'com.firebaseui:firebase-ui-database:3.3.0'
implementation 'com.firebaseui:firebase-ui-auth:3.3.0'
implementation 'com.firebaseui:firebase-ui-storage:3.3.0'

//noinspection GradleCompatible
implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-core:17.0.0'
implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-ads:17.0.0'
implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-auth:17.0.0'
implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-database:17.0.0'
implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-storage:17.0.0'
implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-messaging:17.0.0'
implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-invites:17.0.0'

implementation 'id.zelory:compressor:2.1.0'

implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-auth:17.0.0'
implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-ads:17.0.0'

//    GoogleServicesPlugin.config.disableVersionCheck = true
}

apply plugin: 'com.google.gms.google-services'
```

It has become so hard since Google forced me to update my Compiled Version to 28 while launching it. Now i have to deal with Dependency Issue everytime. 
Can i please know where i have gone wrong? I have tried all the existing solutions in StackOverflow and GItHub multiple times

Answer (score 0):

When you use AndroidX, you should change dependencis. All packages in AndroidX live in a consistent namespace starting with the string androidx. The Support Library packages have been mapped into corresponding androidx.* packages. for example 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7' in your dependency changes to implementation 'androidx.appcompat:appcompat'

According to Google documentation:

> AndroidX replaces the original support library APIs with packages in
>   the androidx namespace. Only the package and Maven artifact names
>   changed; class, method, and field names did not change.

With Android Studio 3.2 and higher, you can migrate an existing project to AndroidX by selecting Refactor > Migrate to AndroidX from the menu bar. But if you want to do it manually you can find proper mapping [here](https://developer.android.com/jetpack/androidx/migrate/artifact-mappings) .

But I recommend delegate it to Android Studio.
It is not without grace to point AndroidX version. Unlike the Support Library, AndroidX packages are separately maintained and updated.

The androidx packages use strict Semantic Versioning starting with version 1.0.0. You can update AndroidX libraries in your project independently:

> All new Support Library development will occur in the AndroidX
>   library. This includes maintenance of the original Support Library
>   artifacts and introduction of new Jetpack components.

Currently(as I,m writing this post), last stable version is AndroidX 1.0.0

And Finally, if you prefer not to use AndroidX, in addition to change dependencies, don't forget to set false two flags in project gradle.properties file.